# gulp serve ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: node.js, gulp

Trying to run gulp serve an getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:47:5
    at req_ (D:\Sharepoint\SPFx\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (D:\Sharepoint\SPFx\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Sharepoint\SPFx\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

gulp versions:
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1

node version:
v16.17.0

npm version:
8.19.1

I tried a bunch of things I found online but none of them were any help.

Comment: What are the "bunch of things" you've tried?

Comment: @sean tried updating and downgrading gulp, but it just gave me lots of errors and didn't work

Comment: What is `fs.js`?